# Spherical harmonic transform with irregular grids on sphere surface

Tags: python, fft, data-processing

Let's suppose I have a number of data points on the surface of a sphere. These data points lie randomly scattered on the sphere surface, i.e. they aren't distributed on a regular grid such as a Gaussian grid.

My question is: Is there a Python library available that allows me to compute the spherical harmonic transform of this data set? Otherwise, I first have to interpolate the data points onto a regular grid by myself before applying a standard spherical harmonic transform.

For non-uniform Fourier transforms I found several options, e.g. [this one.](https://github.com/jyhmiinlin/pynufft) However, for non-uniform spherical harmonic transforms (which are of course related to Fourier transforms) I found none so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this is an old question, but I'll post this anyway.

One of the best libaries available for spherical harmonics in python or Fortran is [shtools](https://shtools.oca.eu/shtools/index.html). Specifically, check out the function [SHExpandLSQ](https://shtools.oca.eu/shtools/pyshexpandlsq.html), which uses a least-squares method to find the spherical harmonic expansion coefficients on an irregularly sampled grid.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a way, that you first interpolate your data points to a regular grid ? If yes, numpy/scipy has methods for doing that. Have a look in the the manuals:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html

and a simple example explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749140/how-to-make-a-matrix-out-of-existing-xyz-data)  (method 2)